# C# entity framework 6 -How to get count from DbSet.RemoveRange Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I get the count from the `DbSet.RemoveRange` Method?  When I attempt to use `Count()`it throws an error when saving changes

```
_dbFileManagementRepository.FileManagements.RemoveRange(_dbFileManagementRepository.FileManagements.Where(x => x.Id == serviceId && x.DateAdded < purgeDate)).Count();
_dbFileManagementRepository.SaveChanges();
```

When I assign it like this, then nothing gets deleted on save changes

```
var records = _dbFileManagementRepository.FileManagements.RemoveRange(_dbFileManagementRepository.FileManagements.Where(x => x.Id == serviceId && x.DateAdded < purgeDate));
int purgeCount = records.Count();
_dbFileManagementRepository.SaveChanges();
```

When I just run this, it deletes just fine:

```
_dbFileManagementRepository.FileManagements.RemoveRange(_dbFileManagementRepository.FileManagements.Where(x => x.Id == serviceId && x.DateAdded < purgeDate));
_dbFileManagementRepository.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With RemoveRange you need two queries no matter you do, so this should be fine for your case:

```
var toBeRemoved = _dbFileManagementRepository.FileManagements.Where(x => x.Id == serviceId && x.DateAdded < purgeDate).ToList();
var removedCount = toBeRemoved.Count;
_dbFileManagementRepository.FileManagements.RemoveRange(toBeRemoved);
_dbFileManagementRepository.SaveChanges();
```